# Page not found when I log out, any idea why the logging out doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-urls

Working on a social app with django and clicking on the log out doesn't work anymore for some reason I get: Page not found (404)

No profile found matching the query
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout
Raised by:  network.views.<class 'network.views.ProfileDetailView'>

Using the URLconf defined in project4.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
[name='all-profiles-view']
 [name='profile-view']
The current path, logout, matched the last one.

Also is there an easy way to make the user's name clickable from any page directed to their profile(ProfileDetailView)??
URLs:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views
from .views import (
    posts_of_following_profiles,
    like_unlike_post,
    invites_received_view,
    invite_profiles_list_view,
    send_invitation,
    remove_friends,
    accept_invitation,
    reject_invitation,

    ProfileDetailView,
    PostDeleteView,
    PostUpdateView,
    ProfileListView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path("", ProfileListView.as_view(), name="all-profiles-view"),
    path("<slug>", ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name="profile-view"),
    path("posts/", views.post_comment_create_view, name="posts"),
    path("posts-follow/", posts_of_following_profiles, name="posts-follow"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("liked/", like_unlike_post, name="like-post-view"),
    path("<pk>/delete", PostDeleteView.as_view(), name="post-delete"),
    path("<pk>/update", PostUpdateView.as_view(), name="post-update"),
    path("invites/", invites_received_view, name="invites-view"),
    path("send-invite/", send_invitation, name="send-invite"),
    path("remove-friend/", remove_friends, name="remove-friend"),
    path("invites/accept/", accept_invitation, name="accept-invite"),
    path("invites/reject/", reject_invitation, name="reject-invite"),
    path("to-invite/", invite_profiles_list_view, name='invite-profiles-view')

]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Views:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, resolve_url, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.core import serializers
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from itertools import chain


from .models import Relationship, Post, Profile, Like
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, View, UpdateView, DeleteView, ListView, DetailView
from .forms import ProfileModelForm, PostModelForm, CommentModelForm

class ProfileDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'network/profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.request.user)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        rel_r = Relationship.objects.filter(sender=profile)
        rel_s = Relationship.objects.filter(receiver=profile)
        rel_receiver = []
        rel_sender = []
        for item in rel_r:
            rel_receiver.append(item.receiver.user)
        for item in rel_s:
            rel_sender.append(item.sender.user)
        context["rel_receiver"] = rel_receiver
        context["rel_sender"] = rel_sender
        context["posts"] = self.get_object().get_all_authors_posts()
        context["len_posts"] = True if len(self.get_object().get_all_authors_posts()) > 0 else False

        return context



@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = ProfileModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)
    confirm = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            confirm = True

    context = {
        'profile': profile,
        'form': form,
        'confirm': confirm,
    }
    return render(request, 'network/profile.html', context)

@login_required
def invites_received_view(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    qs = Relationship.objects.invitations_received(profile)
    results = list(map(lambda x: x.sender, qs))
    is_empty = False
    if len(results) == 0:
        is_empty = True

    context = {
        'qs':results,
        'is_empty': is_empty,
    }

    return render(request, 'network/invites.html', context)

@login_required
def accept_invitation(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        pk = request.POST.get('profile_pk')
        sender = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        receiver = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        rel = get_object_or_404(Relationship, sender=sender, receiver=receiver)
        if rel.status == 'send':
            rel.status = 'accepted'
            rel.save()

    return redirect('invites-view')

@login_required
def reject_invitation(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        pk = request.POST.get('profile_pk')
        receiver = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        sender = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        rel = get_object_or_404(Relationship, sender=sender, receiver=receiver)
        rel.delete()
    return redirect('invites-view')

@login_required
def invite_profiles_list_view(request):
    user = request.user
    qs = Profile.objects.get_all_profiles_to_invite(user)

    context = {'qs': qs}

    return render(request, 'network/to_invite_list.html', context)

@login_required
def profiles_list_view(request):
    user = request.user
    qs = Profile.objects.get_all_profiles(user)

    context = {'qs': qs}

    return render(request, 'network/profile_list.html', context)

class ProfileListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'network/profile_list.html'
    #context_object_name = 'qs'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Profile.objects.get_all_profiles(self.request.user)
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.request.user)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        rel_r = Relationship.objects.filter(sender=profile)
        rel_s = Relationship.objects.filter(receiver=profile)
        rel_receiver = []
        rel_sender = []
        for item in rel_r:
            rel_receiver.append(item.receiver.user)
        for item in rel_s:
            rel_sender.append(item.sender.user)
        context["rel_receiver"] = rel_receiver
        context["rel_sender"] = rel_sender
        context["is_empty"] = False
        if len(self.get_queryset()) == 0:
            context["is_empty"] = True

        return context

@login_required
def send_invitation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pk = request.POST.get('profile_pk')
        user = request.user
        sender = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        receiver = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)

        rel = Relationship.objects.create(sender=sender, receiver=receiver, status='send')

        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    return redirect('profile')

@login_required
def remove_friends(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pk = request.POST.get('profile_pk')
        user = request.user
        sender = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        receiver = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)

        rel = Relationship.objects.get(
            (Q(sender=sender) & Q(receiver=receiver)) | (Q(sender=receiver) & Q(receiver=sender))
        )
        rel.delete()
        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    return redirect('profile')

@login_required
def like_unlike_post(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
        post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)

        if profile in post_obj.liked.all():
            post_obj.liked.remove(profile)
        else:
            post_obj.liked.add(profile)

        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=profile, post_id=post_id)

        if not created:
            if like.value=='Like':
                like.value='Unlike'
            else:
                like.value='Like'
        else:
            like.value='Unlike'

            post_obj.save()
            like.save()

        data = {
            'value': like.value,
            'likes': post_obj.liked.all().count()
        }
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
    return redirect('posts')

@login_required
def post_comment_create_view(request):
    qs = Post.objects.all()
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    #Setting up pagination
    p = Paginator(qs, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    post_list = p.get_page(page)

    #Post form, comment form
    p_form = PostModelForm()
    c_form = CommentModelForm()
    post_added = False

    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if 'submit_pForm' in request.POST:
        print(request.POST)
        p_form = PostModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            instance = p_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = profile
            instance.save()
            p_form = PostModelForm()
            post_added = True

    if 'submit_cForm' in request.POST:
        c_form = CommentModelForm(request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():
            instance = c_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = profile
            instance.post = Post.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
            instance.save()
            c_form = CommentModelForm()

    context = {
        'qs': qs,
        'profile': profile,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'c_form': c_form,
        'post_added': post_added,
        'post_list': post_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'network/posts.html', context)

@login_required
def posts_of_following_profiles(request):

    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    users = [user for user in profile.following.all()]
    posts = []
    qs = None

    for u in users:
        p = Profile.objects.get(user=u)
        p_posts = p.post_set.all()
        posts.append(p_posts)

    my_posts = profile.get_my_posts()
    posts.append(my_posts)
    if len(posts) > 0:
            qs = sorted(chain(*posts), reverse=True, key=lambda obj: obj.created)

    #Setting up pagination
    p = Paginator(posts, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    post_list = p.get_page(page)

    #Post form, comment form
    p_form = PostModelForm()
    c_form = CommentModelForm()
    post_added = False

    if 'submit_pForm' in request.POST:
        print(request.POST)
        p_form = PostModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            instance = p_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = profile
            instance.save()
            p_form = PostModelForm()
            post_added = True

    if 'submit_cForm' in request.POST:
        c_form = CommentModelForm(request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():
            instance = c_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = profile
            instance.post = Post.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
            instance.save()
            c_form = CommentModelForm()

    context = {
        'posts': qs,
        'profile': profile,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'c_form': c_form,
        'post_added': post_added,
        'post_list': post_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'network/followers_posts.html', context)

class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'network/confirmDelete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts')

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        obj = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if not obj.author.user == self.request.user:
            messages.warning(self.request, 'You need to be the owner of the post in order to delete it!')
        return obj

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = PostModelForm
    model = Post
    template_name = 'network/update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        if form.instance.author == profile:
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            form.add_error(None, "You need to be the owner of the post in order to update it!")
            return super().form_invalid(form)


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Attempt to sign user in
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "network/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "network/login.html")


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                "message": "Username already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "network/register.html")
```

Layout:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Social Network{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
        <link href="{% static 'network/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'network/icon.jpg' %}">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Black&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo:700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- jquery -->
        {% block scripts %}
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'network/script.js' %}" defer></script>
        {% endblock scripts %}
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'all-profiles-view' %}">Network</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><strong>{{ user.username }}</strong></a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'posts' %}">All Posts</a>
                </li>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'posts-follow' %}">Following</a>
                    </li>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>

        <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
            {% block body %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your `urlpatterns`. You have `profile-view` before `logout`.

```
path("<slug>", ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name="profile-view")
.
.
.
path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout")
```

And when your logout urls matches with the `slug` and your `ProfileDetailView` is called since your `ProfileDetailView` is evaluated before `logout_view`. So change the ordering of your urls becaues with every `value` after `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` match that pattern and will be called. So reorder your `urls.py` and check.

So by looking at `urls.py` it will not effect on putting this `ProfileDetailView` at bottom of `urls`.

For the second part by clicking on  `username`  call `ProfileDetailView` change in your html as

```
    <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile-view' user.username %}"><strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>. 
              </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: I'm trying but nothing works so far, how do you suggest I reorder them? @user8193706

Comment: Put the slug url at the last of your urls.py

Comment: It woorks thank you! Any solution for the second thing I mentioned? @user8193706

Comment: What will you send in slug value? And where do you want to put in your html?

Comment: @kingmathers92 see I have updated my answer for your second case too.

Comment: User's slug. In the layout to "{{ user.username }}" and on posts card header to "{{ obj.author.user }}" @user8193706

Comment: I have not seen post card header in html but you can do exactly same as in `{{user.username}}` just put your profile url name in href then it will work there too.

Comment: Getting the same error I got earlier with the logout-view, guess I have to reorder urls again. You helped me a lot though, thank you so much @user8193706

Comment: After putting the `urls` at last you got same error ?

Comment: Yes sir @user8193706

Comment: In your `logout` function you use `reverse(index)` and there is no any url's name `index` in your ` urls` .Is there any url where name = `index` in your urls

Comment: Yeah that's an old html file, already been replaced with "login" @user8193706

Comment: For `reverse` you have to import all your url configuration files and import each view function name. If there is any error in your import then it will raise error. So import all your view function name in `urls.py` and use it below.You have not imported all your views in import or either use views.YourFunctionName in all your urls and remove import part since you have already imported `from . import views`. And let me know if it works.

Comment: Tried both and didn't work, maybe it doesn't have to do with the urls. Because for example for my profile username the slug that appears in the address bar is "khaled" but in the admin panel the slug is "khaled-07-01-2022". Maybe it has something to do with that, that's why it says "Page not found (404) No profile found matching the query" @user8193706 if you don't mind we chat on Reddit better, (kingmathers9) is my name on there.

Comment: Anything? @user8193706